# Disable instantiate and button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is issue that i facing with two objects and one button. One is cube second is ground when we click on button cube is collide with ground destroy and instantiate again. On Cube collision score is decrement.Also in hierarchy there is Empty game object which name is controller which has method of text score.Score is working fine but i want that when score is 0 then button click does not work and cube is not instantiate.

Cube :
[image]

Ground :
[image]

Controller :
[image]

CubeScript:

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D body;

    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        body.isKinematic = true;
    }

}
```

Ground Script:

```
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour {

    private Button button;
    private BoxCollider2D collide;
    public GameObject object1Clone;

    void Start () {

        collide = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        collide.isTrigger = true;

        button = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Button").GetComponent<Button> ();

        button.onClick.AddListener (() => Magnetic ());

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {

            Destroy (target.gameObject);
            Instantiate (object1Clone, new Vector3 (0f, 4.12f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);

    }

    public void Magnetic(){

        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;

    }


}
```

ScoreScript:

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int Score=1;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {

        if (Score <=0) {



        } else {
            Score--;
            Controller.instance.SetScore(Score);
        }


    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    public static Controller instance;
    public Text scoreText;

    void Start () {
        scoreText.text = ""+1;

        if(instance==null){

            instance=this;
        }

    }

    public void SetScore(int score){

        scoreText.text =""+score;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the listener registration to this:

```
 button.onClick.AddListener (Magnetic);
```

this will make it easier to remove the listener.

I will show you two ways of doing it, an easy one and a proper one a bit harder to grasp. So if you don't quite get it, use the first and learn about the second.

Every time you decrease the score, check for it and call for the appropriate action:

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int Score=1;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) 
    {
         Score--;
         Controller.instance.SetScore(Score);
         if(Score <= 0){
            GameObject.Find("ground").GetComponent<Ground>().ClearButtonListener();
         }
    }
}
```

And in the Ground component:

```
public void ClearButtonListener()
{
    button.onClick.RemoveListener (Magnetic);
}
```

Now the second more appropriate way would be to use event and listener

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour, IScoreHandler {
    public static int Score=1;
    public event Action OnScoreZero = () => {};
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) 
    {
         Score--;
         Controller.instance.SetScore(Score);
         if(Score <= 0){
            OnScoreZero();
         }
    }
}
public interface IScoreHandler{ event Action OnScoreZero; }
```

And your listeners listens.

```
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour {

    private Button button;
    private BoxCollider2D collide;
    public GameObject object1Clone;
    private IScoreHandler scoreHandler = null;
    void Start () {
        scoreHandler = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<IScoreHandler>();
        if(scoreHandler != null){
             scoreHandler.OnScoreZero += ClearButtonListener;
        }
        collide = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        collide.isTrigger = true;

        button = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Button").GetComponent<Button> ();

        button.onClick.AddListener (Magnetic);
    }
    void OnDestroy(){
         if(scoreHandler != null){
              scoreHandler.OnScoreZero -= ClearButtonListener;
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks to interface and event, your class is no more relying on another class but on an interface which makes it more flexible and scalable.

Comment: Your Ground is ground, typo. I see you are going the easy way :).

Comment: Actually since Ground component and ScoreScript component are on the same object you can skip the object search and only use GetComponent

Comment: if i use your first method then score stop on 0 and not click on 0 score

Comment: why you put space on Action OnScoreZero compiler say it wrongs

Comment: That is just how you declare an Action. You need System namespace as well with: using System;. I don't quite get what you mean with it stops on 0 and not on click. Please avoid saying things like "reply the comment", it sounds like an order. I am entitled to be away from my computer for a while you know, like I would have a life outside of it.

Comment: every one has outside life but give your satisfied answer to user in second method could you explain what are you doing why you declear Action and where it's come from and your second method is wrong cannot work correctly when i use this it does not terminate when score is 0 Fix your second method

Comment: and tell me difference between `button.onClick.AddListener (Magnetic)` or `button.onClick.AddListener (Magnetic())`

Comment: Action is from .NET, it is a delegate. The difference between the two ways is that the first is lambda while the second uses the method name. Since you are not doing anything else but calling he method in lambda there is no reason to use the first. As for your problem of zeroing, you need to explain what you expect the method to do. When is the zero effective and how?

Comment: second method in your answer not stop the cube instantiate when score is 0

Comment: Add a boolean and check for it before instantiation. Set that boolean to false when you call the ClearButtonListener.

Comment: could you help me in this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249370/prefab-doesnot-activate-when-collide-with-object

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the field `interactable` of the `UnityEngine.UI.Button` object to `false`, see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html, i.e. use

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
    if (Score <=0) {
        /* disable the button */
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Button").GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
    }
```

in your `ScoreScript.cs`.